# Как анализировать свой сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование

Вопрос очень наклонут в сторону полемики. Если кратко, то какие знания, технологии, или ресурсы нужны для анализа сайта(Или сервера на котором стоит сайт) для оптимизации самого сайта? К примеру информация о посещениях и о пользователях. IP и локация.

P.S Имееться ввиду не громосткий софт. Не разгрызите меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изучения аудитории, посещений, мест куда больше кликают и многого другого:

1. [Google Аналитика](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/?authuser=0#/provision)
2. [Яндекс метрика](https://metrika.yandex.ru/)

Для оценки качества сайта я использую [Яндекс Вебмастер](https://webmaster.yandex.ru/)